# how to add button A to Z in datalist control in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

how to implement button from a to z in datalist control C#, and then after clicking on button it gives the value of selected button in asp.net c#

Comment: Sorry, there is not enough to help you here. What exactly are you trying to do? Please be more descriptive - you say "clicking on button" - which button - the a-z button for your data list control, some other button?

Comment: actually I want to add A to Z button in my web page.and after clicking on any button,I want to show datalist record according to letter wise. For Example - If I click on A button ,I want to show every author name which first letter start with A,......If I I click On B,I want to show every author record which start with B .....as continue to Z .......I want to show every author name record which are saved in database according to letter

Comment: Okay, do you have any code that you have written that you can provide here?